# Why does this alert show me 'undefined' instead of current month's value?

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I execute this code alert shows me 'undefined' instead of the current month's value

```
function jump() {
    selectYear = document.getElementById("start"); // used for jump section
    selectYear = selectYear.value.toString().slice(0,4);
    selectMonth = document.getElementById("start"); // used for jump section
    selectMonth = selectMonth.value.toString().slice(5,7);
    currentYear = selectYear.value;
    currentMonth = selectMonth.value;
    alert (currentMonth);
    window.value = 0;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}
```

Comment: `currentMonth` is `selectMonth.value`. `selectMonth` is a string. Strings don't have a `.value` property.

Comment: it worked with parseInt() ,thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to parse it from string to integer. `selectMonth` is a string, so therefore it doesn't have a `.value` helper.

You can use the `parseInt()` function to solve this issue instead of using the `.value` helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
function jump() {

    selectYear = document.getElementById("start").value;
    selectYear = selectYear.value.toString().slice(0,4);
    selectMonth = document.getElementById("start").value;

    selectMonth = selectMonth.value.toString().slice(5,7);
    currentYear = selectYear.value;
    currentMonth = selectMonth.value;

    alert (currentMonth);
    window.value = 0;
   showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}
```